# Which Drupal module support spatial filtering with apache solr module

Tags: 7

Which Drupal module support spatial filtering with apache solr module.
like either Location,geofield,geolocation,getlocation or any other.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look to the [Search API Location](http://drupal.org/project/search_api_location) module. There is also demo site.

> The Search API spatial module (7.x-2.x branch) adds the possibility of location based searching to the Search API module.
>   Currently only Apache Solr is supported as server.
>   You can find a demo on http://spatial.mollux.be.

Comment: it provide support for geolocation module but i want location module

Comment: Mh, the location values from the location-module aren't present at the fields to collect in solr-index .. I've tried to use as computed-field, but no solution yet...

Comment: I have same question,could help this library? http://www.solarium-project.org/